# Multithreading with sqlalchemy and flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-multithreading

I have two example models as shown.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id   = db.Column(....)
    name = db.Column(....)
    ....

class Transaction(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(....)
    user_id = db.Column(ForeignKey('User.id').....)
    ....
```

I have a function which takes in user_id as an argument.

```
def add_transaction_for_user(user_id: int):
    '''Does some processing, finds out if transactions
    are missing and adds them if needed.
    '''
    # The part of the question that needs answering Q1 #

    # DB operations querying
    foo = query_foo_for_user(user_id)

    # non DB operations
    missing_transactions = find_transactions_from_foo(foo.property) 
    
    if missing_transactions:

        # DB operations inserting 
        add_transactions(missing_transactions)
    ....
```

I have an API route which is called by a cronjob everyday.

```
@some_blueprint.route('/transactions/autoadd', methods=['POST'])
def autoadd():
    '''Searches and adds missing transactions.
    '''
    all_user_ids: list[int] = query_all_users() # [1, 2, 3...]

    # The part of the question that needs answering Q2 #
```

I have 1000s of users and doing this sequentially will take hours and that is why I need to use multi-threading to optimize the workflow because each user is independent.
I have a few questions.

Q1. Can I just simply create `session = Session()` a scoped_session and pass it in to every function marked with `#DB operations`? because I cannot put all the underlying code in one function I have created small functions to do specific work but none of the examples pass in session as an argument, do I have to call `Session.remove()` inside this function or outside once work is done?

Q2. I know I would have to use something like

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
for user_id in all_user_ids:
    executor.submit(auto_add_transaction_for_user, user_id=user_id)
```

but should I create a session in the route and pass `executor.submit(...., session=s,....)` for every user_id? or let every thread create it's own?

Q3. What would be the simplest example of using multithreading in this context?

Thanks for all the help in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: Is it correct that `find_transactions_from_foo` only needs `foo.property`, but nothing else from `foo`? If true, how does `add_transactions` know which `User` to add the transactions to?

Comment: @van, I just wanted to give a rough idea of the nature of work I do and the above example must not be taken in a literal sense, meaning that is the actual code, but still as you can see user id being passed into the first function and the query result will be ```foo``` unique to that user which will in-turn give transactions unique to that user.

Comment: Please, excuse my weird question(s), but what is the nature of these missing transactions? Should it be possible to archive the result with only `INSERT INTO ... SELECT... WHERE...` kind query in a single or series of transactions? Cardinality of thousands doesn't look like a problem. Hundreds of thousands or millions - maybe. Parallelism may also be a question addressing SQL engine, not an application.

Comment: Yes @Dmitry, most of these queries are infact some type of ```SELECT * FROM``` and once all the manipulation is done few ```INSERT INTO..```, and I am talking about 1000s to 10000s of transactions and not millions, at least as of now.
If the number of users exceeds even to a few thousands, like 3k or 5k, I just keep getting session error when using the default ```db.session``` without any scoping, and use of scoping doesn't seem to have done anything as I still keep getting ```DetachedInstanceError``` on ```Foo``` like objects, I am using flask with sqlalchemy >2.0

Comment: I would use multiprocessing instead of multithreading and I would have a process Queue that each worker would pull from, with the queue populated with users. Have the workers spin up their own session to the DB (makes life 100% easier). Keep in mind that depending on your DB design, this may not actually help you, due to locks and lock escalation.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT... WHERE...` implies that the update process can run only on the DB side, but the question indicates a non-DB process needs to run to understand the missing data.

Comment: Yes, there several calculations that need to be done on the data, for example the number of days that have passed between today and the day the row was last updated.

Answer (score -1):

I would start something like this :

1. Use SQLAlchemy's `scoped_session`: To work with SQLAlchemy in a multi-threaded environment, it's recommended to use a `scoped session`. `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, an extension for `Flask`, provides a `scoped_session` that automatically creates a new session for each thread and keeps the session open for the duration of the thread.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

2. Flask Application Configuration: Set `threaded=True` in your Flask application configuration. This tells Flask to use `multiple threads for handling requests`.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'your_database_uri'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'pool_pre_ping': True  # Enable pre-ping to check for stale connections
}
app.app_context().push()  # Push an application context for thread-local data
```

Comment: Although I appreciate the effort, this is not the answer because you have not actually given an example of how to use ```scoped_session``` to solve the problem from I asked in the question. You have to actually show not just tell that we have to use scoped_session.